Chrome extension script opens a new tab, but runs the script in the original one
I've been fighting this for a couple of days now.
Basically I am on a website, and there is a text field in my extension which then opens a new tab and goes to the same website but with specific search terms. Then it needs to scrape that new tab, but instead it scrapes the original tab I was on. It correctly does the scrolling part of the script on the new tab, but the scraping itself is done on the original tab.
I have the following files:
background.js

content.js

manifest.json

popup.js

popup.html

I am not sure what exactly is the issue.
But here's my background.js:
    //open a new browser window and navigate to the LinkedIn search URL
    chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
      // Open a new window
      chrome.windows.create(
        {
          url: "LINK",
          type: "popup",
          state: "maximized",
        },
        (newWindow) => {
          // Inject content script when the tab is fully loaded
          chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, info) {
            if (info.status === "complete" && newWindow.tabs[0].id === tabId) {
              chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: newWindow.tabs[0].id },
                files: ["content.js"],
              });
              // Remove the listener after injecting the script
              chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
            }
          });
        }
      );
    });
    
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
      if (request.action === "processPageData") {
        // Process the HTML content received from content script
        const pageHTML = request.pageHTML;
        // Send the page HTML to content script for processing
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
            action: "processPageData",
            pageHTML,
          });
        });
      }
    });

And this is my popup.js:
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      // Function to send LinkedIn search data to content.js
      document
        .getElementById("getDataButton")
        .addEventListener("click", function () {
          const searchKeywords = document.getElementById("searchField").value;
          const maxScrolls = document.getElementById("maxScrollField").value;
    
          if (!searchKeywords) {
            alert("Please enter search keywords.");
            return;
          }
    
          // Format the search keywords
          const formattedKeywords = searchKeywords.trim().replace(/\s+/g, "%20");
          const searchUrl = `LINK`;
    
          // Send message to content.js in the currently active tab
          chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
              action: "getLinkedInData",
              searchUrl: searchUrl,
              maxScrolls: parseInt(maxScrolls, 10) || 5, // Default to 5 if not a number
            });
          });
        });
    });

I suspect that the issue is here somewhere, but in case the content.js is needed as well it can be found here - https://pastebin.com/WzFx7GFq

Remove chrome.tabs.query in onMessage and use sender.tab.id instead of tabs[0].id.
